# one side set in many-to-many relation

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, entity

I have three database tables: Customer, Product and PurchaseOrder (for mapping). I am using openjpa for peristence in java rest application.
To all of the tables I have corresponding entities:
Customer

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({...})
public class Customer implements Serializable {
...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customerId")
    private Collection<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrderCollection;
```

Product

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({...})
public class Product implements Serializable {
...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productId")
    private Collection<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrderCollection;
```

PurchaseOrder

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase_order")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({..})
public class PurchaseOrder implements Serializable {
...
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "order_num")
    private Integer orderNum;
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Customer customer;
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product product;
```

What is the best way to get all the customers who ordered a product with specific id?
I **could create** namedQuery, I **could build criteria** with joins etc. But i think there could be a better way how to **make use of the mapping entity** (what would be point of this entity otherway?). Something like setting the productId to the purchaseOrder entity and then fetch all the customers via purchaseOrderCollection in customer entity? But i cannot figure it out. Is there other way than custom/named query or criteria building?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured it out, it can be this way

```
    long productId = //get the id

    Product product = entityManager.find(Product.class, productId);
    Collection<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrderCollection = product.getPurchaseOrderCollection();
    if (purchaseOrderCollection != null) {
        List<Integer> customers = new ArrayList<>(product.getPurchaseOrderCollection().size());
        for (PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder : product.getPurchaseOrderCollection()) {
            customers.add(purchaseOrder.getCustomerId());
        }
        return customers;
    } else {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST; // or null;
    }
```

feel free to offer better sollution :)